# External email account in Gmail ignores disable images setting

Tags: gmail, images

I added a secondary POP3 email account to my Gmail account but it's not following the applied rules for displaying images.

I've marked **Ask before displaying external content** in Gmail settings but I think this only works for my Gmail account because all images or most of them from my other account are shown on the messages.

Images from MercadoLibre, Apple, Stack Exchange and many other sources are not displayed but the images from some customers appear. I think it's because I answer them but I don't want to display their images too.

Could this behavior be stopped?

[Display images from certain senders](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=145919)
 from Gmail Help says yes but it doesn't work for external accounts emails.